# Indicate room owners and mods in mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

I just got hit with the new mobile chat. It's awesome.

One thing that is missing is identification of room owners and mods in chat. I'd like to see italicized names for room owners and blue names for mods, just like desktop chat.

It was always missing from the old interface and I was hoping it'd make its way into the new one.

Comment: Huh, never noticed RO got italicized names but now that you said it, can't un-see it. :D

Comment: Hmm. I never noticed that either ;) And I'm a room owner ...

Comment: So a mod who is also a room owner should be *blue* (blue **and** *italic*)?

Comment: @DavidPostill It should be whatever it is on the desktop site.

Comment: @JasonC Agreed. I was just thinking that maybe the desktop site is wrong as well ;)